# Flask SQLAlchemy Union All "Compound Object is not iterable"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

i'm trying to union couple queries based on my query params by using sql-alchemy,flask and marshmallow. I use db.union_all to union all my BaseQuery objects that return from my models. However, i get an error saying `'CompoundSelect' object is not iterable`. union_all query returns selectable compound object with the correct query but the problem occurs when i try to serialize with @dump method.

I also tried using union_all this way and this works with my serializer class. However, i can't use this approach because I have to dynamically create my union query as i don't know if facebook_data or pinterest_data will even exist. Assuming i will have lot of publishers and each of them will have different combinations, it might be ugly to write several if conditions since this code snippet depends on having at least one publisher exist as the left statement of the code before union_all

```
q=facebook_data.union_all(pinterest_data)
return publisher_schema.dump(q)
```

Models;

```
class BasePublisher(Model):
    __abstract__= True
    id= Column(db.String(80),primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    date = Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    views = Column(db.Numeric)
    clicks = Column(db.Numeric)
    publisher = Column(db.String(80),primary_key=True,nullable=False)

class Facebook(BasePublisher):
    __tablename__='facebook_table'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, **kwargs)

class Pinterest(BasePublisher):
    __tablename__='pin_table'
    
    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, user=user, **kwargs)

class Twitter(BasePublisher):
    __tablename__='twitter_table'
    
    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, user=user, **kwargs)
```

---

Schemas

```
class PublisherSchema(Schema):
    date = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
    type = fields.DateTime(dump_only=True)
    views = fields.Number(dump_only=True)
    clicks = fields.Number(dump_only=True)
    publisher = fields.Str(dump_only=True)

class FacebookSchema(PublisherSchema):
     @post_dump
     def dump_data(self,data):
           data["type"]="Facebok"

class PinterestSchema(PublisherSchema):
     @post_dump
     def dump_data(self,data):
          data["type"]="Pinterest

class TwitterSchema(PublisherSchema):
     @post_dump
     def dump_data(self,data):
          data["type"]="Twitter"
```

View

```
@blueprint.route('/api/sample/publishers/<id>', methods=('GET',))
@use_kwargs({'type': fields.Str(), 'start_date': fields.Str(),'end_date':fields.Str()},location="query")
def get_data(id, type, start_date=None,end_date=None):

    facebook_data = Facebook.query.filter_by(id=id)
    .filter(Facebook.date.between(start_date,end_date))
    .limit(10)

    pinterest_data = Pinterest.query.filter_by(id=id)
    .filter(Pinterest.date.between(start_date,end_date))
    .limit(10)

     twitter_data = Twitter.query.filter_by(id=id)
    .filter(Twitter.date.between(start_date,end_date))
    .limit(10)

all_queries=[facebook_data,pinterest_data,twitter_data]
golden_set = db.union_all(*all_queries)

publisher_schema.dump(golden_set) -->ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not directly related to this question.
But I used this line of code to make Compoundselect object iterable:

```
golden_set = db.session.execute(golden_set)
```

Where golden_set is union result.